# GET parameters on ajax call (into modal dialog)

Tags: javascript, ajax

On an html page i click on a link and i get a dialog which loads server content through an ajax call.

I cannot change the javascript that created this dialog neither the ajax callbacks .

I have the need to access the href of the clicked link from another javascript to change some content loaded into the dialog from the ajax call. This after the dialog shows up.

As i can only read the window.location of the current page (the page containing the dialog, not the page loaded into the dialog itself), is there a way to get the href of the clicked link that caused the dialog to show up ? (ie. the GET parameters of the ajax call)

Attaching a callback for every clicked link doesn't work reliably because i have to catch just the last one that caused the dialog to open...

-- edit --

Well i'm using jquery, but i don't think it's implementation dependant.

The question more generally is: if i cannot access the ajax callback, is there a way to obtain the url in the GET request that caused a div (some content) to update ? (assuming you can call a javascript function **after** the div is loaded, inside it).

ie. if it was a popup (window.open) i just have to read window.location to get the page called, but as it's a div loaded from an ajax request, how i can get the url called ?

thanks anyway~

Comment: Some code samples would be helpful. Is your "dialog" a new window or just a div?

Comment: that's a div (with server side content) inside an existing window

Comment: @gunzip, are you using any libraries (e.g. jQuery, Prototype.js, etc.)?  Can you post some of the code?

Comment: Are you using a dialog/pop-up script that we can look at?

Comment: As I understand this, you want to "access" some kind of fetched-urls history isn't?
Maybe, I'm telling you this without looking anywhere else, you can play with the XHR object, try to code some kind of "event handler" for fetched urls.
Honestly I don't see an easy way to do this in your scenario.

Comment: thank you, i resolved intercepting all clicks on anchors and storing a fetched url history.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install Firefox (if you do not have it already)
2. Install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/index.html) extension
3. Enable firebug for your site
4. Click the Link that launches the dialog (reproduce the situation)
5. Open the firebug window (bottom right corner of firefox)
6. Under Net - >XHR tab you can see the **exact** URL call with **all** GET/POST parameters that was triggered.

Then explore firebug some more to see what other possibilities it offers!